# How do I validate a name consisting of two columns?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

How do I validate a name consisting of two columns with simple validate call, or with a validator method?

I have a name consisting of two column, `firstname` and `surname`. A record is valid only when `firstname + surname` is unique.

If I add `firstname: "lala la"`, `surname: "le li lo"` it is valid because it is the only one.

If I enter `firstname: "lala"`, `surname: "la le li lo"`, and the concatenation of `firstname` and `surname` is the same in both examples, the second shouldn't be valid.

I cannot find simple way to do this.

I tried things like:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :firstname, :surname, :scope => {:firstname, :surname}
```

or combinations of this, but that didn't work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291240/rails-models-and-unique-combinations

Comment: I'd do it with a unique compound key in the database to maintain its integrity. Your code then reacts to an exception when inserting and updating. It's an alternate way to handle the problem, but is very traditional and is probably how a legacy database would be set-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstname="lalla", surname= "leli"

and

firstname="la", surname= "llaleli" are different,so following validation can't validate it

```
validates :surname, :uniqueness => { :scope => :firstname }
```

try this

idea is that compute full name(in a callback like before_validation) and store it in table(So you need another column) now add validation on that column

```
before_validation :compute_fullname
validates :fullname, :uniqueness => true


def compute_fullname 
   fullname = (first_name+surname).replace ' ',''  #i don't like gusb you can try it too
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot this one works nice, but the replace there doesnt work, but anyway iam used to .tr(" ","") and in the controller I had to assign that fullname like : user.fullname = user.compute.full_name otherwise it was doing just nothing i dont know why? :O and on the _form I had to put there disabled input for this fullname, because the error was not visible otherwise, I will see if I can improve that somehow :P thanx a lot guys

Comment: glad to help you, and i think fullname should be protected so user can't set value for it with mass assignment

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
validates :surname, :uniqueness => { :scope => :firstname }
validates :firstname, :uniqueness => { :scope => :surname }
```

**EDIT**: that could be done with [validates_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_with) but beware to performance if you want to test your edge case from the question where:

```
firstname: "lala la", surname: "le li lo"
```

is a duplicate of :

```
firstname: "lala", surname: "la le li lo"
```

Comment: that was quick, but this doesnt quiet do the magic you see when I have the case I wrote up there it says the second one is valid...
I somehow need to validate those params joined together with those from table joined together... but how ? :(

Comment: You might want to take a look at that then: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_with

Comment: @Redrick modified my answer to add validates_with